# Add a push segue to a button inside of a custom cell of a tableview

Tags: ios, button, tableview, segue, custom-cell

I have a project that displays a feed of statuses similar to other social networks. Each feed item has several button that do different things. 1 of the buttons opens a new viewcontroller that displays the comments that have been posted on a particular status. When this button is clicked and the view controller is opened i would like it to be a push segue so that their is a back button and the user can navigate back to the feed.

When this button is clicked and the new vc is launched some unique data about the particular status/cell being clicked needs to be sent to the "comments vc ". Where would the code for doing this go?

CUSTOM CELL .H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FeedItemCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DefaultImg;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *NameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *StatusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *msg_id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* commentButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* bumpButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
-(IBAction)viewComments:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)bump:(id)sender;

@end


@protocol CustomCellProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)EBCellPressed:(NSString *)cellName;
```

CUSTOM CELL .M

```
#import "FeedItemCell.h"
#import "CommentsViewController.h"
#import "NSDate+TimeAgo.h"


@interface FeedItemCell() <WYPopoverControllerDelegate>
{


}
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender;
- (void)close:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation FeedItemCell
@synthesize commentButton;
- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = delegate;
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)bump:(id)sender{

    [self.delegate EBCellPressed:@"NAME"];



}

- (IBAction)open:(id)sender
{

}








@end
```

publicFeed . M

```
#import "PublicFeedViewController.h"
#import "FeedItemCell.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "InboxDetailViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "CommentsViewController.h"
#import "NSDate+TimeAgo.h"


@interface PublicFeedViewController (){
    NSArray *NameLabel;
    NSArray *StatusLabel;
    NSMutableArray *feedArray;
}

@end

@implementation PublicFeedViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //The below code prompts the user for push notifications. If allowed, code in AppDelegate takes over and stores the token.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.FeedTable.dataSource=self;
    self.FeedTable.delegate=self;

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
    [manager POST:@"www" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        self->feedArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"feed"];

        [self.FeedTable reloadData];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return feedArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    FeedItemCell *Cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!Cell){
        Cell = [[FeedItemCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    NSLog(@"FEED ARRAY: %@", self->feedArray);
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self->feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Display recipe in the table cell
    NSString *thumb_img = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"thumb_img"];
    NSString *thumb_path=@"http://buhzhyve.com/CI_REST_LOGIN/UPLOADS/thumbs/";
    NSString *thumb_url = [thumb_path stringByAppendingString:thumb_img];



    Cell.NameLabel.text=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    Cell.StatusLabel.text=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
    Cell.msg_id=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"msg_id"];
    //Cell.status=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
    Cell.StatusLabel.lineBreakMode=0;
    Cell.StatusLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    NSString *commentCount = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"comment_count"];
    NSString *commentButtonText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Comments ( %@ )",commentCount];
    [Cell.commentButton setTitle:commentButtonText  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *bumpCount = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"bump_count"];
    NSString *bumpButtonText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bumps ( %@ )",bumpCount];
    [Cell.bumpButton setTitle:bumpButtonText  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    //[Cell.StatusLabel sizeToFit];
    NSString *created_string=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"created"];
    double created_double = created_string.doubleValue;
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:created_double];
    NSString *ago = [date timeAgo];
    Cell.timeLabel.text=ago;




    //Cell.DefaultImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buhz_mini_logo.png"];

    [Cell.DefaultImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumb_url]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buhz_mini_logo.png"]];
    return Cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Ideally you should do lazy loading so that instead of creating a new textView each time, you just reuse the same one.
    UITextView *temp = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(82, 26, self.FeedTable.frame.size.width, 18)]; //This initial size doesn't matter
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self->feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *status = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
    temp.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:12];
    temp.text = status;


    CGFloat textViewWidth = 218;
    CGRect tempFrame = CGRectMake(82,26,textViewWidth,18); //The height of this frame doesn't matter.
    CGSize tvsize = [temp sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(tempFrame.size.width, tempFrame.size.height)]; //This calculates the necessary size so that all the text fits in the necessary width.

    //Add the height of the other UI elements inside your cell

    return tvsize.height + 70;


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"commentSegue"]) {

    }
}

@end
```

publicfeed .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PublicFeedViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *FeedTable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
- (IBAction)addItem;



@end
```

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that you're creating this button in code, this is how you could handle this.

This first line tells the button that when it's pressed, it needs to call this specific selector/method sent as the action.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showNextViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then you would create this method in the same class.

```
- (void) showNextViewController
{
    NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];  //Edit this line of course to fit for your situation.  I'm not sure if you're loading from an XIB or from a Storyboard, or neither.
    newViewController.someVariable = someVariable;
    newViewController.someOtherVariable = someOtherVariable;

    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

This will send the necessary data to the new view controller, and it will also display the new view on the screen with a back button.

Hope this works!

Comment: Yes, inside of your custom cell.

Comment: cant access navigation controller from within the custom cell so i did some searching and came across this: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42902-call-pushviewcontroller-from-a-custom-uitableviewcell.html 


but, that doesnt work either bc i need to send the msg_id from the specific cell that was clicked to the commentsviewcontroller and using the way they described in that link i dont see a means of doing that.

Comment: Try this     [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];  This should give you access to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Ok so lets pretend this is your custom cell class.
in your .h file of the custom cell you need to add a protocol.**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate; //this is used for sending messages out of the custom cell

//init
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andCatName:(NSString *)name andDelegate:(id)delegate;

@end
@protocol CustomCellProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)customCellSelected:(NSString *)cellName;

@end
```

what we actually did is something like creating a custom event that the class can throw out and everyone who subscribes to that can run a method when `customCellSelected` is thrown.

**2. now when you create each custom cell with the `init` method you need to provide a delegate which kind of points to which class should the custom cell transfer the call to `customCellSelected` so in the init method you set that delegate.**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)delegate {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = delegate; //setting which class should be called when calling protocol methods.
        // Your initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

**3. now in your .m file of the custom cell, when the user presses your button and you enter your method , let it be `buttonPressed`**

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate customCellSelected:@"THE CELL'S NAME"]; // calling the protocol method.
}
```

now the call to the delegate method should be transferred to the vc because when you create the custom cell you use `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)delegate` and you transfer `self` as the delegate , so when `[self.delegate customCellSelected:@"THE CELL'S NAME"];` is called it is actually called on the vc.

**4. this is how you create the custom cell in the vc:**

```
customCell *tempView = [[customCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, Height) andDelegate:self]; // here you set the vc as the delegate
```

**5.and now all you have to do is add the method `customCellSelected` to your vc code so it can called when the customCell is calling it.**

```
- (void)customCellSelected:(NSString *)cellName {
    self.selectedCell = cellName;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SelectedCell" sender:self];
}
```

**6.then add this in the vc:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SelectedCell"]) {
        LevelSelectViewController *levelSelectViewController = (LevelSelectViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        levelSelectViewController.cellName = self.selectedCell;
    }
}
```

**7.only thing you have to remember is to create a segue from your first vc to the second like this:**

[image: how to create segue]

Comment: and how exactly do i go about calling :[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue1" sender:self]; 

from the custom cell class?

Comment: @ChuckKelly you can either init each cell with instance of `self` or use protocol and delegation and throw for example `cellPressedCall` to your viewController and then invoking it. I've added code for the delegation.

Comment: I added some source code of my own to the original question, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me and i feel like were close, but I lost you when you started talking about what i need to do on the view controller side of things. I never had to deal with delegates in android so alot of these concepts are new to me.Would you mind telling me exactly what I need to add to the vc still? I find once i have something working its alot easier to pick it apart and understand how it works.

Comment: @ChuckKelly I've updated the answer for a tut with all you need to get this going.

Comment: You've helped me more than enough but I'm still confused, I don't get how initwithframeframe plays into my custom cell or where the "catName"param comes from or what it's for. I think I Need to just keep studying or searching for a sample that builds to pick apart, thank you for your time though your help did help me make some progress in my head conceptually

Comment: Couldn't I accomplish the delegate step without initwithframe and just set the delegate in view did load or something ? Maybe It's just not clicking for me I now understand that protocols are a set of "rules" that must be followed in order for them to be used by the class that inherits them , but ur loosing me on the delegate stuff.

Comment: @ChuckKelly yes you can achieve it without using the init, just do something like this: 'customCell.delegate = self;' that's perfectly good, doing it in the init is just for convenience. You should read about protocols a bit before moving on, even tho you can still use the code I supplied without, I think it will he better for you to learn about protocols first.